# Python 2.7 or 3.1.2?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python 2.6 or python 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508906/python-2-6-or-python-3-1)

Hi,
I'm new to the python world and it seems that there are currently two parallel versions in development, which would be the 2.7 versus the 3.1.2. I'm wondering what version should I use to start, and why?

Comment: This question has already been asked on SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170921/to-learn-python-2-then-3-or-3-from-the-start

Comment: Yeah, i saw that but since it was in october 09, the anwser could have been deprecated. It seems the development has continued on both versions.

Comment: The new development hasn't changed the reasoning behind the answers.

Comment: P.S. You might want to ask the question "How do I find out which libraries are/aren't supported in Python 3.1?" although I suspect that one has been asked already too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest Python 3 as it has incorporated several fixes to remove some of Python's previous "warts". The primary reason for maintaining the 2.7 version is for older packages that haven't yet made the transition. There are good reasons to use 2.7 but if you're starting out, you might as well start on the path leading to the future.

Comment: Unless you get into Python, start to like it, then discover all the treasure in Matplotlib, NumPy, PySerial, wxPython, ..., and all the other things that you can't use.  Then you'll wish you had chosen "2.6"  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Stay with 3.1.2 if you want to be on the bleeding edge.

Stay with 2.7 if you want to leverage any 3rd party libraries that haven't been ported to 3.1.2 yet or can't be backward compatible.